# Access csv file within HTML file in NodeJs

Tags: html, node.js

I making an app using NodeJS. Instead of jade it uses HTML file in views directory. This HTML file is trying to access a csv file but is unable to do so. I get this in my console GET /data.csv 404 5ms

Is something wrong with the path?

Right now in HTML accessibility is like this

```
d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
```

Comment: Sorry. Autocorrection was on. Rectified it.

Comment: Your server is probably not configured to serve static files. Are you using Express?

Comment: Yes, I am using express.

Comment: I added an answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you probably didn't configure `express` to serve static files.

If you installed `express` globally

```
npm install -g express
```

then you can run

```
express <app_name>
```

which will generate a skeleton app for you. You can see there the folder structure that you need to follow. Typically you will need to put static files such as `data.csv` into the `public` folder, so they can be picked up by a GET request.

The static folder configuration part is done in your code by this line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

(which is also present in the sample app generated by the `express` command)